# sockstat of php-fpm doesn't match config file

Tags: freebsd, socket

I am trying to get a test system up and running under FreeBSD (actually under a TrueNAS jail) using nginx, php and php-fpm. This is the first time I've tried to build such a system, and FreeBSD isn't my first language.

I am confused about what is in the php-fpm config file, versus what is being reported by the sockstat command.

The php-fpm config file has the expected entry of:

```
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

But when I run sockstat, I get this result:

```
root@FNMPTest:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d # sockstat -4 | grep php-fpm
www      php-fpm    91271 6  tcp4   192.168.1.223:9000    *:*
www      php-fpm    91270 6  tcp4   192.168.1.223:9000    *:*
root     php-fpm    91269 8  tcp4   192.168.1.223:9000    *:*
```

I expected to see 127.0.0.1 in the sockstat output, but 192.168.1.223 is the IP of the jail the system is running under.

Is what I am seeing in sockstat the expected result?  Why I am not seeing 127.0.0.1?

---

1. I have nginx serving up the default index.html, but so far I am failing to get it to serve up a simple php page.  I don't know where the actual issue lies, but this is the place that I am starting to question what is going on.
2. If I change the socket number in the php-fpm config, I do see that change reflected in sockstat output.